# NMaximize/NArgMax complain about nonnumerical value (::nnum) when working with a region

Tags: mathematical-optimization

### Finding the mode of a SmoothKernelDistribution

I am using a smooth kernel approximation to a mixture distribution to find the distribution's mode (e.g. by using `NArgMax`). To demonstrate the issue that I am facing I have reproduced it by simply using a normal distribution:

```
SeedRandom["NArgMax160404"];
sample = RandomVariate[ NormalDistribution[ 5, 3 ], 10^6 ];
region = Interval[ {0, 10} ]; (* the region of definition/interest *)    
dist = TruncatedDistribution[ { 0, 10 }, SmoothKernelDistribution @ sample ];
Plot[ Evaluate @ PDF[ dist, x ], x \[Element] region, Filling-> Axis, Axes -> {True, False} ]
```

[image: PDF]

### Using `NArgMax` without any constraints

This looks rather unspectacular and finding its mode does not give problems:

```
NArgMax[ PDF[ dist, x ], x ]
```

> 4.97893

### Using `NArgMax`/`NMinimize` with a region or constraints gives error

Using `NArgMax` with the given *region* will cause an error:

```
NArgMax[ PDF[ dist, x], x \[Element] region ]
```

[image: regionError]

Giving the region as a *constraint* is (contrary to [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMax.html)) will give the same error message:

```
NArgMax[ { PDF[ dist, x ], x \[Element] Interval[ {0, 10} ] }, x ]
```

**What is going on here?**

Comment: I should add that I am using **Version 10.4** on Windows 10 Pro (64).

Comment: (comment recast as an answer)

Comment: It seems the question has been edited a bit and no longer matches the answer...

Comment: @ilian you were too quick and I have *learned* from your comment. :) It still does match your answer but the question is now rather precisely driving at the problem of 1D regions.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [73465](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73465/764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of using the correct syntax. Since `Interval[{0, 10}]` is a one-dimensional region, its elements have the form `{x}` instead of just `x`:

```
RandomPoint[Interval[{0, 10}]]

(* {3.23781} *)

Element[%, Interval[{0, 10}]]

(* True *)
```

The documentation for `NArgMax` does say

> `NArgMax[... , x ∈ reg]` constrains `x` to be in the region `reg`

but here `x` is of course a vector variable, since `reg` could have any dimension. This fact is also made clear a little further down in the details,

> For `x ∈ reg`, the different coordinates can be referred to using `Indexed[x, i]`

Vector variables are also illustrated in the last two *Scope* examples on the same page.

Therefore, the input for the first example should be

```
NArgMax[PDF[dist, x], {x} ∈ Interval[{0, 10}]]

(* 4.97893 *)
```

For the second example -- originally given as `NArgMax[ { PDF[ dist, x] && 0 <= x <= 10}, x ]` and now edited out by the OP -- that's not how constraints are specified. The given objective function has head `And` and evaluates to `False`, which is not a number. Instead, try

```
NArgMax[{PDF[dist, x], 0 <= x <= 10}, x]

(* 4.97893 *)
```

or

```
NArgMax[{PDF[dist, x], {x} ∈ Interval[{0, 10}]}, x]

(* 4.97893 *)
```

Comment: The problem is indeed 1D regions and not a simple RTFM error. For regions and `NArgMax` the documentation gives: *NArgMax[{f,cons},x∈reg] is effectively equivalent to NArgMax[{f,cons∧x∈reg},x].* Maybe I missed a good example somewhere for 1D?